# Who is stronger, Naruto or Sasuke?

Tags: naruto

If there was an all out fight between Naruto and Sasuke, who will win?
Basically, who is stronger, Sasuke or Naruto?

Comment: this can be argued a lot, However according to the series it seems they are equally as strong.

Comment: The manga basically ends with them having an all-out brawl to the death.  They tie.  And almost bleed out.  Pretty definitive, especially given how that entire arc was about how they were two sides to the same, balanced coin, right down to their karmic inheritance.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy This should be cleaned up into an answer.

Comment: possibly naruto if he is very serious and micro-planner. however it is contrary to naruto's character

Comment: @Hansen You are the strongest, if you follow your ninja way

Answer (score 3):

This will create a long debate. However, it is mentioned multiple times throughout the series that they have **equal strength**. Naruto knows this by exchanging fists with Sasuke, he specifically tells that to Sasuke in the Shippuden episode (spoiler alert!):

> Where Sasuke kills Danzo, and then goes after Kakashi by almost killing Sakura

In the end of the series, Kishimoto gives an answer to this:

> Naruto and Sasuke have an all-out fight to death because Sasuke believes in order to protect the world from evil, he has to cut all emotional ties. And, quote Sasuke, "[Naruto] you are my only friend". This battle ends with both of them losing an arm, and heavily bleeding until Sakura saves them.

It is implied that they both have equal strength.

Comment: Can we say that the two is the part of the same coin ?!? (the share so much and think so differently )